# What is battery performance like on the Nexus 7 when running Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

While running Android, advertising claims the Nexus 7 has a 8 - 11 hours of battery time, Many users claim to get around 6 - 9 hours depending on what type of activity they are doing. Have there been any benchmarks done on the tablet while running Ubuntu?  Is it Better or Worse?

Answer (score 2):

[Preliminary testing](http://victorpalau.net/2012/11/06/ubuntu-nexus7-7-hours-battery-life-whilst-browsing/) has shown comparable battery life. There are plans for more rigorous testing in the near future. Stay Tuned!!

Answer (score 2):

I've done some research on this too: http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/non-linear-characteristics-in-draining.html

My findings are:

Screen not dimmed, idle: ~12 hours battery life.
Screen not dimmed, 4 CPUs fully loaded: ~7 hours battery life.
I've not yet exercised the GPU.